# Random number generator using $dist_uniform in SystemVerilog

Tags: random, verilog, distribution, system-verilog, modelsim

I am trying to generate a random number using the `$dist_uniform` using Quartus and ModelSim.

The relevant code section is as follows (within a loop):

```
rand= $dist_uniform(10,20,25);
rand_test=$random;
```

'rand' is always 20 while 'rand_test' is varied on every iteration.

Would appreciate any advice on the matter.

I have tried many variations of the `$dist_uniform` as well as other distributions as well - the only way I have succeeded to generate a random number is by the `$random` command.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to the `$dist_uniform` function should be an integer variable, not a constant.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.15.2 *Distribution functions*.

> $dist_uniform ( seed , start , end )
>
> ... the seed argument is an inout argument; that is, a value is passed
> to the function, and a different value is returned.

This produces 10 random integers between 20 and 25:

```
module tb;

integer rand_test, seed;

initial begin
    repeat (10) begin
        rand_test = $dist_uniform(seed, 20, 25);
        $display(rand_test);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Also, `rand` is a SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800) keyword.  Trying to assign to it should give you a compile error.  Many simulators require you to explicitly enable SV features.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `$dist_random` has a constant seed, so it always returns the same random value. In SystemVerilog, you should be using `$urandom_range(maximal, minval=0)` instead of `$dist_uniform(seed, start, end)`, as well as `$urandom` instead of `$random` Even if your design is in Verilog, these system function should still be available for use in your testbench.

The `$urandom` function in SystemVerilog have much better *uniform* distributions of values and offer much better random stability (the ability to reproduce the same series of random values for debugging stimulus).